# How can I show TinyMCE in a page?

Tags: tinymce

I just setup TinyMCE in a test page from my server, but nothing happens. Textarea still in default, without Tiny commands and format line.

Can you help me, please?

The test page is https://monono.com.br/arebo/an/tiny.php

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#teste"
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
      'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
      'table emoticons template paste help'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
      'bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | ' +
      'forecolor backcolor emoticons | help',
    menu: {
      favs: {title: 'My Favorites', items: 'code visualaid | searchreplace | emoticons'}
    },
    menubar: 'favs file edit view insert format tools table help',
    content_css: 'css/content.css'
  });
```

`selector: "#teste"` should have a comma after it. I see an error in the console about an unexpected identifier which is probably because there is no comma and it is not a valid object

Answer (score 1):

Your page throws an error in the browser's console:

```
tiny.php:12 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

If you look at that line in the PHP file you will see you have a malformed JavaScript object as you don't have a comma after the selector:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#teste"
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
```

...should be...

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#teste",
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
```